# Python web application with separately processing

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm writing a web application in python (googleappengine) that works this away:

User upload raw data and some info through a web form.
The app reads the info and the raw data and makes a lot of processing over the data.

Some of this processing requires a web request to check some information.
Since some of these web requests take some seconds to finish, the app encounters a timeout.

I want to know if there are someway of processing the data separately.
I can show a message to the user saying that the data are "in the oven" and when processing is over it will show the data.

How can I run it separately? How can I know when it got finished?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to offload the processing to a [deferred task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred).

In your request handler, create a key value to associate with the task.  Pass the key value and the data for processing to the deferred task.  Return the key value to the client (I'm assuming the request is being submitted via javascript).

Have the task write the result of the processing to the datastore or store it in memcache (but note that memcache may delete the result without warning).  Use the key value from the handler as the datastore or memcache key.

On the browser side, have your javascript send periodic requests containing the key to another request handler which will return data when it finds it in storage, otherwise returns a 'Not ready yet' message.